# Starting with plain (non material ui) canvas in flutter

Tags: flutter

All tutorials and documentation I've seen so far start of with importing flutter material. I am wondering is this an absolute requirement? What if I want to start with a plain canvas and build my own theme / widgets. Can I do this, if so what package should be used here so I get access to default widgets?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Although the answers here are correct, I want to add a few more points. To use raw widgets use `import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';`
Here is a working example:

```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
      child: Directionality(
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,

      child:Text("hello world",

                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 1)
                  ),
      )));
  }
}
```

The directionality is needed, the padding was added so that we see the message, otherwise it is masked by the menubar in phone.

Answer (score 11):

Widgets in flutter makes the developers day easy. All the widgets are built on top `dart:ui` lib. It is up to you, to decide to use existing set of widgets or develop your ui from scratch. Flutter does not stop you from writing your own widgets.

You can find a few raw example of [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/examples/layers/raw), that does not use any widgets at all.

If you simple don't want only material widgets, then you can just build your own themed widgets with all other [basic widgets and layouts](https://flutter.io/widgets/) available in flutter.

If you wanted to  build few of your own widgets with a canvas and use it along with other widgets in flutter, you look into [CustomPaint](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/CustomPaint-class.html) and [CustomPainter](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/rendering/CustomPainter-class.html) widgets.

Hope this helped!

Comment: I've got a follow up question actually, after looking through UI package it seems like something that is very hands on and should be used for extremely custom ui. My original question tended more towards using things like `Text`, `Row` etc.. components, that I don't think are specific to material ui. Is there a sort of `default` import I can use for these that just spits them out as plain widgets without iOS or Material styling

Comment: Yes, things like `Text`, `Row` etc are basic widgets on top of which `Material` library is built. If you just wanted to use these basic widgets then just `import "package:flutter/widgets.dart"`. For all basic widgets, you can check the docs [here](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/widgets-library.html)

Answer (score 1):

Just as [Chandan Purohit answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53895534/14298786), use `import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';`. Flutter official gives a minimal app in [Introduction to widgets](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/widgets-intro) as follows:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    const Center(
      child: Text(
        'Hello, world!',
        textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Just change `flutter/material.dart` to `flutter/widgets.dart`, and you get a plain canvas to start.

Note: The color of `Text` is white by default.